qiskit.providers.basic_provider.exceptions.BasicProviderError: 'basic_simulator encountered unrecognized operation "ucry"'
I need some help in running circuit on qiskit==1.0 simulator.
The documents says:
https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/migration-guides/qiskit-1.0-features
from qiskit.providers.basic_provider import BasicProvider
backend = BasicProvider().get_backend("basic_simulator")
result = backend.run(qc).result()

This instructions work well for basic gates.
But If there is some special gate as shown in the circuit as shown below, I get the error:
qiskit.providers.basic_provider.exceptions.BasicProviderError: 'basic_simulator encountered unrecognized operation "ucry"'


The actual code I am trying out is below:
 backend = BasicProvider().get_backend("basic_simulator")
 print(qc_combine.draw())
 job = backend.run(qc_combine, shots= shots_used)
 result = job.result()
 counts = result.get_counts(qc_combine)

I am missing some step in between. It would be great if I can be guided on this.

You should transpile your quantum circuit before passing it to backend.run. Something like pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=1) and then qc_combine = pm.run(qc_combine).

Thank you @TristanNemoz for great great help.

Did that solve your question? Just to know if I can post it as an answer, so that we can close the post!

Thank you @TristanNemoz for great help. This solution worked exactly as you have written.

Qiskit (and also Aer if I'm not mistaken) requires you to transpile your circuit before passing it to a backend. This can now be done using the pass manager like so:
pm = generate_preset_pass_manager(backend=backend, optimization_level=1)
qc_combine = pm.run(qc_combine)

Add these lines before backend.run and you should be good to go.

Thank you for great help @TristanNemoz.
